# Cannot login to SMTP server Postfix/Imap Courier/Plesk

Tags: authentication, smtp, imap, postfix-mta, plesk

I have problems connecting on SMTP to the email server.

I'm trying to send email with PHPMailer and this is the error I get:

```
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: encryption needed to use mechanism
"SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: encryption needed to use mechanism
"SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: encryption needed to use mechanism
CLIENT -> SMTP: RSET
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 2.0.0 Ok
"SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 2.0.0 Ok
"SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.0.0 Ok
exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.' in C:\Projects\oicrm\protected\components\phpMailer\class.phpmailer
```

I have tested with another email server and it works fine, so it must be something wrong with the server configuration.

The server is running Postfix, Courier Imap and Plesk control panel.

Also has installed the fail2ban tool.

Hours ago it was running Dovecot instead of Courier but I have removed it and installed Courier thinking that this will solve it but with no luck.

I have also did tweaking to Postfix master.cf but with no luck.

I'm thinking that the problem could be either misconfiguration in email server, or maybe ssl/auth issues on server, or maybe some firewall causing problems?

Just tried to connect by telnet 25 and got this:

```
[root@eldeposit postfix]# telnet mail.oibarcelona.com 25
Trying xxx.xxx.140.235...
Connected to xxx.xxxxxxxxx.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ns334238.ip-xx-xx-xx.eu ESMTP Postfix
EHLO ns334238.ip-xx-xx-xx.eu
250-ns334238.ip-xx-xx-xx.eu
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 30720000
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
AUTH LOGIN
503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled
```

Providing here my configuration:

```
[root@ns334238 postfix]# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
disable_vrfy_command = yes
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 30720000
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = ns334238.ip-37-187-140.eu
mynetworks =
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
plesk_virtual_destination_recipient_limit = 1
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org
smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noplaintext
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/ns334238.ip-37-187-140.eu.pem
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_tls_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: tls_ssl_options=NO_COMPRESSION
```

And another one:

```
[root@ns334238 postfix]# postconf -M
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
pickup     unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
plesk_virtual unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DORhu user=popuser:popuser argv=/usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/postfix-local -f ${sender} -d ${recipient} -p /var/qmail/mailnames
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=R user=mailman:mailman argv=/usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/postfix-mailman ${nexthop} ${user} ${recipient}
pickup     fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
plesk_saslauthd unix y   y       n       -       1       plesk_saslauthd status=5 listen=6 dbpath=/var/spool/postfix/plesk/passwd.db
qmgr       fifo  n       -       n       1       1       qmgr
smtps      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=no -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
plesk-example-domainbarcelona.com-XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX- unix - n n - -     smtp -o smtp_bind_address=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4 -o smtp_helo_name=example-domainbarcelona.com
plesk-example-domaintrend.com-XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX- unix - n n -   -       smtp -o smtp_bind_address=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4 -o smtp_helo_name=example-domaintrend.com
plesk-example-domaintrend.com-XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX- unix - n n -  -       smtp -o smtp_bind_address=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4 -o smtp_helo_name=example-domaintrend.com
plesk-example-domainbarcelona.fr-XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX- unix - n n -  -       smtp -o smtp_bind_address=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4 -o smtp_helo_name=example-domainbarcelona.fr
plesk-example-domainbarcelona.co.uk-XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX- unix - n n - -     smtp -o smtp_bind_address=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4 -o smtp_helo_name=example-domainbarcelona.co.uk
plesk-example-domainbarcelona.de-XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX- unix - n n - -       smtp -o smtp_bind_address=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4 -o smtp_helo_name=example-domainbarcelona.de
plesk-example-domainmallorca.com-XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX- unix - n n - -      smtp -o smtp_bind_address=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4 -o smtp_helo_name=example-domainmallorca.com
plesk-example-domainmgzn.com-XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX- unix - n n -    -       smtp -o smtp_bind_address=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4 -o smtp_helo_name=example-domainmgzn.com
plesk-example-domainmallorca.com-XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX-2001-41d0-a-4aeb-- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -o smtp_bind_address6=2001:41d0:a:4aeb:: -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4 -o smtp_helo_name=example-domainmallorca.com
```

Answer (score 6):

Just found the solution by myself:

http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/123719

**Symptoms**

When trying to send email using Roundcube, an error occurs:

```
SMTP Error (250): Authentication failed
```

When connecting via telnet, following output is displayed:

```
# telnet domain.tld 25
Trying 91.204.25.4...
Connected to domain.tld.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 domain.tld ESMTP Postfix
helo l
250 domain.tld
auth login
503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled
```

Mail server does not return authentication mechanisms list:

```
# telnet 1.2.3.4 25
Trying 1.2.3.4...
Connected to 1.2.3.4
Escape character is '^]'.
220 host.tld ESMTP Postfix
ehlo parallels.com
250-host.tld
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 20480000
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

**Cause**

Postfix misconfiguration.

**Resolution**

Check Postfix configuration file at /etc/postfix/main.cf . Comment thee following lines which are responsible for preventing plain text passwords and forcing SMTP connection over SSL or TLS

```
#smtpd_sasl_security_options = noplaintext
#smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
```

Comment: You should be enabling STARTTLS in your client app, not enabling insecurity on your server.

Comment: I was trying the connection with the 3 methods, insecure, ssl and tls. None was working. After changing postfix configuration all 3 are working.